# Maximum number of flips to make all row sums and column sums non-negative

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

(An extension of: [Making all row sums and column sums non-negative by a sequence of moves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404758/making-all-row-sums-and-column-sums-non-negative-by-a-sequence-of-moves) )

You choose integers to be written on each cell of an $m \times n$ grid. At each step, you are allowed to change the sign of every number of a row or of a column, if the sum of the row or column is strictly negative. You want to maximize the number of steps you can take before all row and column become nonnegative. What is the maximum number of steps, and what is a construction of the starting grid and steps taken which achieves this maximum number of steps?

**My progress:**

If we let $F(n,m)$ be the answer to the question, I can show $F(n,m) \geq (2\cdot \min (n,m) - 1) \cdot \min(n,m)$.

The construction is as follows:

Only consider the square case, where $n = m$. If the grid is rectangular, we can truncate the grid. Let the top left corner of the grid be $(1, 1)$, the bottom right corner fo the grid be $(n,n)$. $(i,j)$ refers the the cell in the i-th row and the j-th column. Let $C_i$, and $R_i$ refer to the ith column and ith row.

We can place $-2k$ in the cell $(k, k+1)$, for $1 < k < n$ and place $-2k+1$ in the cell $(k, k)$. Then, we can flip $C_1, R_1, C_2, R_2 \dots C_n$. After the flips, we will have the starting position, but the cell at $(n,n)$ is now positive. We can flip $C_1, R_1 \dots R_{n-1}$, and $(n-1, n)$ is now positive. And, we can keep on going, and this will make $n(2n-1)$ flips.

I had been focusing on the square case, and I ran a brute force which found much better constructions than the above. I conjecture that you can get $F(n, n) = 4n^2 - 7n + 4$ but don't have a way of constructing.

Edit: My conjecture is false. F(4, 4) >= 42.

Here are some results for the brute force (These are all lower bounds):

| f(n,m) | n=1 | n=2 | n=3 | n=4 | n=5 | n=6 | n=7 | n=8 | n=9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **m=1** | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 9 | 11 | 13 | 15 | 17 |
| **m=2** | 3 | 6 | 12 | 20 | 27 | 32 | 38 | 42 | - |
| **m=3** | 5 | 12 | 19 | 26 | 31 | 40 | 43 | - | - |
| **m=4** | 7 | 20 | 26 | 42 | 39 | 48 | - | - | - |
| **m=5** | 9 | 27 | 31 | 39 | 45 | - | - | - | - |
| **m=6** | 11 | 32 | 40 | 48 | - | - | - | - | - |
| **m=7** | 13 | 38 | 43 | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| **m=8** | 15 | 42 | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| **m=9** | 17 | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There seems to be missing words in your text: “… and place Then, we can flip…”